# Cannot update product table getting You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

im still learning codeigniter and have come up with a problem. That is 
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

I am trying to update a table : product which contains product_name, product_desc etc columns below are my controller ,view and model .. i cannot figure out what am i doing wrong .. I always checked out print_r($array); it gives me an empty array ... although i do get product details displayed in the input fields on the link : ci/index.php/admin/product/1 ..

posting half code for view as the view code is long ..

**Controller :**

//**** For editing product ****//

```
 public function edit_products(){


                    $data = array ('product_name'=>$this->input->post('product_name'),
                    'product_desc'=>$this->input->post('product_desc'),
                    'product_stock'=>$this->input->post('product_stock'),
                    'product_sku'=>$this->input->post('product_sku'),
                    'inventory_date'=>$this->input->post('inventory_date'),
                    'product_price'=>$this->input->post('product_price'),
                    'featured_product'=>$this->input->post('featured_product'),
                    'best_seller'=>$this->input->post('best_seller'),
                    'brand_id'=>$this->input->post('brand_id'),
                    );

                    $upd_pr = $this->mainmodel->update_product($_POST);
                     if($upd_pr){
                       $this->session->set_flashdata('messages', 'Updated Sucessfully');


                        redirect('admin/editing_products');

                            }else{
                         $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Updation Failed');
                            redirect('admin/editing_products');
                                }
            }



    public function editing_products(){


$data['product']=$this->mainmodel->set_pro2();
        //$data['images'] = $this->products->images($id);
         $data['content']='admin/edit_products';

         $this->load->view('admin/main',$data);       
           }
```

---

**Model :**

```
/*for update Product*/
    public function update_product($array){

        extract($array);


        //print_r($array);
        //die;

    $this->db->update('product',array('product_name'=>$product_name,'product_desc'=>$product_desc,'inventory_date'=>$inventory_date,'product_price'=>$product_price,'featured_product'=>$featured_product,'best_seller'=>$best_seller,'brand_id'=>$brand_id));

$this->db->update('product');



                    return ;
    }


 function set_pro2(){
      $q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM product,product_image,category_product WHERE product.product_id = category_product.product_id   AND product.product_id = 1 LIMIT 1');
```

if($q->num_rows() > 0){

```
        foreach($q->result() as $row){

        $data[] = $row;

        }
        return $data;
        }
}
```

---

**View :**

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-row-seperated" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/edit_products') ?>" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
                    <?php foreach($product as $pro){ ?>
                                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name:<span class="required">
                                                    * </span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $pro->product_name; ?>">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Description: <span class="required">
                                                    * </span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="product_desc"  value="<?php echo $pro->product_desc; ?>">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: In your model, within your update_product function, you have 2 update functions. Remove the second one, and see if that works...

Comment: Thankyou very much i removed the second update and it worked.. but it is updating all the products .. but not the one which is being selected...

Comment: You'll have to set the WHERE. $this->db->where('product_name', $array['product_name']); that is assuming the product name is unique.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases **codeigniter** updates / inserts require `this->db->set` if in array. I also would not recommend placing two `db->update` to the same table as you have added on model.

Active record guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

**Update**

```
// $brand_id = 0, $data are from the edit function on controller
public function name($brand_id = 0, $data) {
$product_name = $this-input->post('product_name');
$product_desc = $this-input->post('product_desc');
$inventory_date = $this-input->post('inventory_date');
$product_price = $this-input->post('product_price');
$featured_product = $this-input->post('featured_product');
$best_seller = $this-input->post('best_seller');

$data = array(
'product_name'=> $product_name, 
'product_desc'=> $product_desc,
'inventory_date'=>$inventory_date,
'product_price'=>$product_price,
'featured_product'=> $featured_product,
'best_seller'=> $best_seller,
'brand_id'=> $this->uri->segment(what_ever)
 );
 $this->db->set($data);
 $this->db->update('product');
 }
```

**Or insert**

```
$data = array(
'product_name'=> $product_name, 
'product_desc'=> $product_desc,
'inventory_date'=>$inventory_date,
'product_price'=>$product_price,
'featured_product'=> $featured_product,
'best_seller'=> $best_seller,
'brand_id'=>$brand_id
 );
 $this->db->set($data);
 $this->db->insert_id();
 $this->db->insert('product');
```

**Post Update**

Set routes `$route['function/edit/(:any)'] = 'folder/products_list/edit/$1';`

If need to update a product you need to set a function called edit on the

Model Get

```
public function model_get_products() {
return $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'products')->result_array();
}
```

**Controller** for uri segment help http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

```
public function edit() {
  Form validation
  $this->load->library('form_validation');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('what ever');

  if ($this->form->validation->run() == TRUE) {
  $this->load->model('folder/model_update_product');

  //Example uri segment admin/product_list/edit/id_number $this->uri->segment('4')

  $this->model_update_product->name($this->uri->segment('what_ever_is'), $this->input->post())

   redirect('function/product_list');

  } else {
    // Load Your Form View i.e. $this->get_form();
  }
}

public function index() {

 $this->load->model('folder/model_get_products');

 $results =  $this->model_get_products->get();

 $data['products'] = array();

//Example uri segment admin/product_list/edit/id_number $this->uri->segment('4')

 // Add What Else You Need to here and then you can add it to view

 foreach($results as $result) {
    $data['products'][] = array(
    'brand_id' => $result[brand_id],
    'edit' => site_url('controller_name/edit'). '/' .$result[brand_id] // site_url must match what you set in routes for edit.
    );
 }

 return $this->load->view('folder/products_list', $data);
}

public function get_form() {
 //Example uri segment admin/product_list/edit/id_number $this->uri->segment('4')

 // Make sure you set another model function in your get model where can get by id.

 $product_info = $this->get_products_by_id->get($this->uri->segment('4'));

  $product_name = $this->input->post('product_name');

  if (isset($product_name)) {
    $data['product_name'] = $product_name; // for name="" in input
  } elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
    $data['product_name'] = $product_info['product_name']; // for value="" in input
  } else {
    $data['product_name'] = '';
  }

  $this->load->view('folder/product_form', $data);

 product form contents
}
```

view product list

```
<form>
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if ($products) { ?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $product['brand_id'];?></td>
<td><a href="<?php echo $edit;?>"> Edit Product</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much i removed the second update and it worked.. but it is updating all the products .. but not the one which is being selected...                  ' public function update_product($array){
   
   extract($array);


  $this->db->update('product',array('product_name'=>$product_name,'product_desc'=>$product_desc,'inventory_date'=>$inventory_date,'product_price'=>$product_price,'featured_product'=>$featured_product,'best_seller'=>$best_seller,'brand_id'=>$brand_id));
  
      return $this->db->get_where('product', array('product_id'=> $user_id))->result(); ;
  }
  '

Comment: Thankyou i have checked your code and it will get me what i wanted but i also tried another way around that was by passing a hidden id field in the form and then getting it in the function. So this gave me the id of the product now it updates only one product and not all of them :)... Thankyou all for helping me out :) ...

Comment: You have to set up a check box and lots more other functions. It's quite complicated to update all products together